# Shared element transitions between Activities not triggered when launching Intent with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I'm trying to perform one `Transition` between to `Activities` that involve a **shared element**.

When I start the Intent without any special flags, the transition is shown as expected.

My problem is when I launch the transition with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flags.
As expected, in this case the target `Activity` is not created as it already exists in the stack, and instead the `Activities` in top of it are destroyed and the `Intent` is routed to the existing instance.
As it happens, it seems that **the `Activity` not been created avoids the Transition to be triggered**.

Has anyone came through this and is there any known workaround?

Code is:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class)
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
final Pair<View, String> sharedElement = new Pair<View, String>(findViewById(R.id.shared_elem_id), "TAG");
final ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, sharedElement);
ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, intent, options.toBundle());
```

When I comment out the line that puts the flags the Transition works.

Answer (score -2):

Try to define animations through style and not at run time. Since activity is neither destroying nor creating second time, it will not display transitions.